# How do I use arrays in cURL POST requests with PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am wondering how do I make this code support arrays?

i'am trying to send parameters via php curl in a stock screener to have the result in this page:
https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/f0171a68-053e-42f2-a941-d6ecdf2ba6d1?offset=25&count=25
[parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJkoc.png)
here is my php code

```
<?php

$url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/screener?lang=en-US&region=US&formatted=true&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com';
// $url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/f0171a68-053e-42f2-a941-d6ecdf2ba6d1';



 $parameters =
  [
   'size' => 25,
   'offset' => 50,
   'sortField' => 'intradaymarketcap',
   'sortType' => 'DESC',
   'quoteType' => 'EQUITY',
   'topOperator' => 'AND',
   'query' => array(
        'operator' => 'AND',
        'operands'=> array(
            'operator' => 'or',
            'operands' => array(
                'operator' => 'EQ',
                'operands' =>  array("region","jp")  
            )
        )
    ),
   'userId' => 'HFEELK3VBE3KPE4MGEA6PZTXXL',
   'userIdType' => 'guid'
  ];
  $parameters = json_encode($parameters);

  $headers =
  [
   'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
   'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
   'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
   'Connection: keep-alive',
   'Pragma: no-cache',
   'Cache-Control: no-cache',
  ];
  $cookie = tmpfile();
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.31');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parameters));
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  var_dump($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parameters));
```

Change this line. If your problem is that you can send the body through curl then probably you need to send it as a json so try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($parameters,true));
```

I saw your comment that you tried to send it already as array and i assume it did not work so i am almost sure that in your post you need to send a json (which is the most common body format for post requests)

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example**

```
$data=array();
$data['amount']=100;
$data['to']='test';
$json=json_encode($data);
$header = array('Content-Type: application/json');
$handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$response=curl_exec($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you pr1nc3 and Gurpal singh

i changed this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parameters));
```

for this one

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($parameters,true));
```

but i always have this result

```
'{"error":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"internal-error","description":"STREAMED"}}}'
```

here again the code

```
<?php

    $url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/screener?lang=en-US&region=US&formatted=true&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com';
    // $url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/f0171a68-053e-42f2-a941-d6ecdf2ba6d1';

    $parameters =
    [
   'size' => 25,
   'offset' => 50,
   'sortField' => 'intradaymarketcap',
   'sortType' => 'DESC',
   'quoteType' => 'EQUITY',
   'topOperator' => 'AND',
   'query' => array(
        'operator' => 'AND',
        'operands'=> array(
            'operator' => 'or',
            'operands' => array(
                'operator' => 'EQ',
                'operands' =>  array("region","jp")  
            )
        )
    ),
   'userId' => 'HFEELK3VBE3KPE4MGEA6PZTXXL',
   'userIdType' => 'guid'
  ];

  $headers =
  [
   'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
   'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
   'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
   'Connection: keep-alive',
   'Pragma: no-cache',
   'Cache-Control: no-cache',
  ];
  $cookie = tmpfile();
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.31');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($parameters,true));
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parameters));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  var_dump($response);

?>
```

i think the error is in the variable $parameters but i don't see where

when i compare view source send

```
{"size":25,"offset":0,"sortField":"intradaymarketcap","sortType":"DESC","quoteType":"EQUITY","topOperator":"AND","query":{"operator":"AND","operands":[{"operator":"or","operands":[{"operator":"EQ","operands":["region","jp"]}]}]},"userId":"HFEELK3VBE3KPE4MGEA6PZTXXL","userIdType":"guid"}
```

with my variable $parameters, there are diferences

```
{"size":25,"offset":0,"sortField":"intradaymarketcap","sortType":"DESC","quoteType":"EQUITY","topOperator":"AND","query":{"operator":"AND","operands":{"operator":"or","operands":{"operator":"EQ","operands":["region","jp"]}}},"userId":"HFEELK3VBE3KPE4MGEA6PZTXXL","userIdType":"guid"}
```